# Save image based on absolute elements

Tags: php, jquery

I want to save image based on absolute positioned elements.
I have got door creator app written in PHP. 
User selects door shape, then decorations. Jquery generate that door with decoration (decoration is an absolute element, so user can create his own door).

But how can I process such thing ? Door are background image and decoration is positioned on this door, I can't use right click and save image, because I will select background or decoration.

Can I merge such image and use it for later use?

Thanks.

Comment: You use canvas for that and post some code here when you have it

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a hash with the values that the user selects and then send that to php.

like

```
var options = {};
options.door = 'user selected door';
options.decorations = {
  pattern: 'zxs',
  positionX: 34,
  positionY: 23
};
```

Then send that as a JSON string to your server.

Comment: Can i have more complex example?

Comment: No. I am not going to write your app for you. This was a general example of a strategy to use. I would suggest learning some more PHP/JavaScript if this doesn't give you an idea.